# Launching Driving Directions with Lat and Long values from another activity

Tags: android

Here's my situation:

- I have a list that will launch different pages for different places.
- Each of these pages already have a WebView and MapView showing the
  details and the map of the respective places (I used a TabHost)
- I created an activity which extends ItemizedOverlay to enable me to place a marker, as well as to launch an alert dialog for my driving directions. This is used by all the MapView

I am able to launch driving directions from the alert dialog through the Google Maps app from my app so far. However, I have to put the lat and long values (actual numbers) in the Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps...").

Is there a way to replace the lat and long values with strings from the Activity of the respective places?

P.S. Please pardon me as this is my first time posting here, and I am very new to programming =)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
String uri = "http://maps.google.com/maps" + String.format( "?daddr=%s,%s",
                                                            getLocationLat(),
                                                            getLocationLng() );
Intent i = new Intent( Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse( uri ) );
startActivity( i );
```

Comment: Hi. so what do I do with getLocationLat() and getLocationLng()? My problem now is that the strings are in different activities from the ItemizedOverlay =(

Comment: If you are launching the intent from the AlertDialog you should be able to access any local variables of the Activity which created it. By making the location object / lat long strings a local variable in the Activity you should be able to access them directly.

Comment: The variables aren't local. They are in a different .java file from the AlertDialog. 

I'm sorry if this is frustrating for you =/

Comment: Can you pass them in as parameters when you construct the AlertDialog? If not you could subclass it, add variables with getters and setters to your new class and add them after creation but before display.]

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know how to do that =( I'll try to google it